# Converting date and time TEXT fields to one INT unix timestamp field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, unix, timestamp

I currently have a mySQL database with two TEXT fields: `Date` and `Time`. These are in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy' and '0:00' respectively, for example '11/08/2020' and 19:12. I want to create a third field called `Timestamp` (of type INT) and convert the two original fields into this timestamp field and remove the date/time text fields.

I have done a bit of research in regards to using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and STR_TO_DATE() but I can't seem to get it to work, the format seems to be wrong for it.

How can I achieve this in SQL and convert two string fields which represent date and time into a third field to replace them both which just stores the unix timestamp?

This is my best attempt so far..

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`InfractionDate`, " ", `InfractionTime`), '%d %M %Y %h:%i%p')) FROM `playerinfractions`
```

The table is called `playerinfractions` and the date/time are stored in the TEXT fields `InfractionDate`and `InfractionTime`.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format pattern that you use in the function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)is wrong.
Try this:

```
SELECT 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE(
      CONCAT(`InfractionDate`, ' ', `InfractionTime`), 
      '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
  )     
FROM `playerinfractions`
```

Comment: Yeah this worked, thanks! I had already tried with the slashes in place previously but it didn't work. It seems changing %M to %m and %h and %H made the difference.

Comment: `m` is used for double digit numeric month and `H` for 24H format. Check the link of the function STR_TO_DATE() in my answer for the proper format.

Comment: How would I go about running a query to update all the fields to be the result of this query? If I run this:

`UPDATE `playerinfractions` SET `InfractionIssuedTimestamp` = (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`InfractionDate`, " ", `InfractionTime`), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')) FROM `playerinfractions`);`
it finds all rows and gives the error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row. What kind of WHERE clause would I factor in here?

Comment: No need for SELECT: `SET InfractionIssuedTimestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(InfractionDate, " ", InfractionTime), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))`

Comment: Ah I see, I was thinking perhaps a subquery wasn't the way to go, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell STR_TO_DATE the correct format of your date and time, which you suggested was  `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( 
            STR_TO_DATE( 
                CONCAT('10/08/2020', ' ', '12:20'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i' ) 
            )
        )
FROM `playerinfractions`
```

So using your columns

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( 
            STR_TO_DATE( 
                CONCAT(`InfractionDate`, ' ', `InfractionTime`), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i' ) 
            )
        )
FROM `playerinfractions`
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried passing a string to the same function in below format and it worked. Also you can share your format to check it further.

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('8/12/2020',' ', '12:01:49' ),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'))
```